# How to get the x y position of a view after zoom-in in android

Tags: android

I am Beginner for android, am looking for xy position of a view in zoom-in page but i tried a lot i cant able to get that.I used this below coding, but im getting the same position before and after the zoom. Please any one post the code for finding the xy position after zoom it.

```
 private int fieldImgXY[] = new int[2];
 v.getLocationOnScreen(fieldImgXY);
 Log.v("Log",fieldImgXY[0]+" "+fieldImgXY[1]);
```

My full code:

```
     zoom = (ZoomView) findViewById(R.id.maincontainerScroller);    

     imageView = new ImageView(this);
     imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
     imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
     zoom.addView(imageView);    

     imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            v.getLocationOnScreen(fieldImgXY);
            Log.v("Log",fieldImgXY[0]+" "+fieldImgXY[1]);

        }
    });
```

Comment: what position? Do you want the relatives or absolute coordinates? the onTouch point?

Comment: if your accessing same view reference x and y are same because here you are doing animation that means original view coordinates doesn't chanage..

Comment: @AndresCardenasPardo i want the absolute coordinates when i click the view(image)...

Answer (score 1):

for take the absolute coordinates from image I use this method:

```
void calculeAbsoluteCoorde(MotionEvent e){
    float []m = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(m);
    float transX = m[Matrix.MTRANS_X] * -1;
    float transY = m[Matrix.MTRANS_Y] * -1;
    float scaleX = m[Matrix.MSCALE_X];
    float scaleY = m[Matrix.MSCALE_Y];
    lastTouchX = (int) ((e.getX() + transX) / scaleX);
    lastTouchY = (int) ((e.getY() + transY) / scaleY);
    lastTouchX = Math.abs(lastTouchX);
    lastTouchY = Math.abs(lastTouchY);
}
```

I supose u used matrix for zoom, i wish it help u

Comment: Sir where i want to call this method in OnClickListener

Comment: then u want the values MTRANS_X and MTRANS_Y of the matrix,but that aren't coordinates. Use imageView.setOnTouchListener, is an imageView, not a button

Comment: Thanks sir, it is working for imageview....... now i need the position for relative layout click point before and after zoom(pinch)....

Comment: Sir please tell me how to display a dialog box near a image when i click it by using this xy position.....

Comment: Sir here i posted the screenshot of my program(update)... i want the dialog box near zoomed position as well as normal position of image